# How to embed MATLAB CTF in shared library?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I've used mcc to build a shared library that has the CTF embeded, and then created a second shared library which actually exposes the interface I need in my application. Thus I have two shared libraries.

However what I want to do is have a **single shared library** containing the CTF but with my wrapping functions exported rather than the mlx/mlf functions that MATLAB generates. I've been unable to find anything in the documentation about this, or anything obvious from the verbose output of mcc/mbuild. I'm certain this is possible.

### Edit

To create the MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR)-linked shared library (DLL) containing the CTF, I run the following command:

```
mcc -v -W lib:libalgorithm -T link:lib algorithm.m
```

This generates `libalgorithm.dll`, `libalgorithm.lib`, and `libalgorithm.h`, among other build files. To expose the desired interface to my application, I create `wrapper.c`, which then calls `mlxAlgorithm`, converting between the types my application can handle and MATLAB's `mxArray`. This is compiled in MATLAB with this:

```
mbuild -v -I. wrapper.c libalgorithm.lib wrapper.exports
```

This generates `wrapper.dll`. I then must carry `wrapper.dll` and `libalgorithm.dll` around, and as I'll be creating many different algorithms, this will create headaches in regards to file management and naming.

So I'd like to simply generate one shared library that exports my desired interface and contains the CTF. I tried the following commands:

```
mcc -v -W lib:libalgorithm algorithm.m
mbuild -v wrapper.c libalgorithm.c wrapper.exports
```

This compiles and links fine, resulting in a single shared library, however the CTF is given as a separate file, `libalgorithm.ctf`, and is not embedded. My application can successfully link and call this library, however when calling the MCR generated function `libalgorithmInitialize` a 'No such file or directory' error results, since the CTF has not been extracted. While I could extract this, this would only worsen the file management problem.

Looking at the verbose output while running these two different command pairs, I cannot see any difference between the resulting build commands, however one library has the CTF embedded and the other does not. **How is the MCR embedding the CTF in the DLL?**

Comment: We have tried to solve similar kind of stuff and just dummy append seemed to work as expected: `copy /B libalgorithm.dll + libalgorithm.ctf libalgorithm.dll`.